# Problems in summing two polynomials using python

Tags: python, dictionary, polynomial-math

I'm asked to make a program that calculates the addition of two polynomials of n and m degrees. I made two dictionaries (one for the first polynomial and the other is for the other polynomial) since each one has the coefficients as values and degrees as keys so that I can check whether the keys from both dictionaries are identical, then I can sum their values. But I don't know why I always get an error. My code so far is:

```
class poly:
    def __init__(self, L=[], D=[]):
       self.coef=L
       self.deg=D

    def __add__(self,L2):
       if len(self.coef)>len(self.deg):
          dec=dict(zip(self.deg,self.coef))
          dec[0]=self.coef[-1]

       else:
          dec=dict(zip(self.deg,self.coef))

       Dec1=dec

       if len(L2.coef)>len(L2.deg):
          dec=dict(zip(L2.deg,L2.coef))
          dec[0]=L2.coef[-1]
       else:
          dec=dict(zip(L2.deg,L2.coef))

       Dec2=dec
       p=[]

       if len(Dec2)>len(Dec1):
          for i in Dec2:
            if i in Dec1:
                s=Dec1[i]+Dec2[i]
                p=p+[s]
            else:
                p=p+p[Dec2[i]]

          for x in Dec1:
            if x in Dec2:
                p=p
            else:
                p=p+[dec1[x]]
       return(poly(p))

       if len(Dec2)<len(Dec1):
         for x in Dec1:
             if x in Dec2:
                g=Dec1[x]
                p=p+[g]
             else:
                p=p+[Dec1[x]]

         for m in Dec2:
            if m in Dec1:
                p=p
            else:
                p=p+[Dec2[m]]
       return (poly(p))
```

This code doesn't work for all my examples such as

```
>>> p=poly([2,4,7,34],[6,4,2])
>>> p1=poly([6,3,7,2,8],[8,4,2,1])
>>> p2=p+p1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    p2=p+p1
  File "poly.py", line 31, in __add__
    p=p+p[Dec2[i]]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> #The numbers in the first list is the coefficients and the second list is for degrees
```

This doesn't work! But it worked when I've done the addition without using class method. I'm a beginner and I did my best to fix the problem.

Another question is how to write the def **str** for my code? I really don't have any idea what I should write in the beginning. I'm sorry guys but I'm new in programming and I need an easy code such as mine.

Comment: Not that its causing your particular problem, but be careful using `[]` as a default value in `__init__` (or anywhere else, for that matter): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Also, it might make more sense to store your polynomial as a single list of coefficients, so that `x^3 + 2` has coefficients `[1, 0, 2]`.

Comment: I did both! first my init was without [] but it didn't work. So i will get ride of it. Sorry for not having mentioned that i'm expecting that the user enters a string!!

Comment: @user1354396: Have you printed out the values you are indexing `Dec2` with in the line that throws that error? I bet you'll find they're not the ones you're expecting ;)

Answer (score 3):

1. By common convention, class names should be capitalized (ie `Poly`)
2. You have `__add__` doing a lot of stuff that has nothing to do with adding. This should be a warning sign.
3. A lot of `__add__`'s work is mucking about with the data storage format. Maybe you should use a better storage format, one which won't need so much reshuffling?
4. You have a lot of repetitive chunks of code in `__add__`; this is usually an indicator that the code should be factored into a subroutine.
5. You have this object (`self`) making changes to the internal details of another object (`L2`) - another bad smell.

If you move the normalization code for self (`if len(self.coef) > len(self.deg) ...`) from `__add__` into `__init__`, this will solve #2, #3, half of #4, and #5 all in one go (you no longer have to "do to" L2, it will "do to" itself).

If you realize that it's pretty much irrelevant whether `len(Dec1) > len(Dec2)` or not, you can get rid of another block of redundant code. This fixes the other half of #4. Suddenly `__add__` shrinks from 48 lines of code to about 12, and becomes much easier to understand and debug.

For sake of comparison:

```
from itertools import izip_longest, chain, product
from collections import defaultdict

class Poly(object):
    def __init__(self, coeff=None, power=None):
        if coeff is None: coeff = []
        if power is None: power = []
        self.d = defaultdict(int)
        for c,p in izip_longest(coeff, power, fillvalue=0):
            if c != 0:
                self.d[p] += c

    @classmethod
    def fromDict(cls, d):
        return cls(d.itervalues(), d.iterkeys())

    @property
    def degree(self):
        return max(p for p,c in self.d.iteritems() if c != 0)

    def __add__(self, poly):
        return Poly(
            chain(self.d.itervalues(), poly.d.itervalues()),
            chain(self.d.iterkeys(),   poly.d.iterkeys())
        )

    def __mul__(self, poly):
        return Poly(
            (cs*cp for cs,cp in product(self.d.itervalues(), poly.d.itervalues())),
            (ps+pp for ps,pp in product(self.d.iterkeys(),   poly.d.iterkeys()))
        )

    def __call__(self, x):
        return sum(c*x**p for p,c in self.d.iteritems())

    def __str__(self):
        clauses = sorted(((p,c) for p,c in self.d.iteritems() if c != 0), reverse=True)
        return " + ".join("{}x^{}".format(c,p) for p,c in clauses) or "0"
```

Note that:

1. Each method is short and does only things relevant to what it is supposed to accomplish.
2. I purposefully wrote `__init__` to be very fault-tolerant; it will cheerfully accept multiple coefficients of a given power and sum them. This allowed me to greatly simplify `__add__` and `__mul__`, basically just throwing all the resulting clauses at a new Poly and letting it clean them up again.
3. I have included a minimal implementation of `__str__`, which will result in moderately ugly output like `5x^2 + -2x^1 + -5x^0`. You may wish to add special handling for negative coefficients and powers of 1 or 0, to make it produce `5x^2 - 2x - 5` instead.
4. This is for the purpose of understanding, not plagiarism; do not submit it to your teacher as is, he will never in a million years believe you actually wrote it ;-)